# Has Rey's new lightsaber been seen before in canon or legends?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, lightsaber, the-rise-of-skywalker

The new *Rise of Skywalker* trailer has Rey (or someone who looks an awful lot like her) wielding a new double lightsaber, but now with action deploy mechanism! (someone in marketing has to be giddy). Darth Maul, eat your heart out.

[image: Rey's new collapsible lightsaber]

Has this weapon been seen or used elsewhere? Canon and Legends acceptable

Comment: Is there any remotely reasonable lightsaber design, that wasn't used? ;)

Comment: Hm, is she going to the [Dagobah cave](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cave_of_Evil)?

Comment: @Mithoron: Fist knife? Throwing star lightsaber? Lightsaber whip?

Comment: @Mithoron this isn't really that reasonable, is it?

Comment: @Damon - Pretty sure a lightsaber whip did show up in the comics at some point.  I know I saw a picture of it somewhere once...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: Such a thing appeared in the 80s trash movie "Johnnie Mnemonic". Abysmal movie, but great idea with the laser whip. Some Yakuza guy who had his finger cut off for honor had it replaced with a techno-magical take-off cap which when taken off would then bring forth the laser whip between the stump and the removed cap. So awesome.

Comment: @Damon Jedi can throw their lightsabers and retrieve them and blasters fire plasma, both are similar to throwing stars in differing ways. Lumiya (and a few other characters) used lightwhips. I don't know of any lightknife at all, but clones could have vibroblade punching knives in Republic Commando and there was the "shoto" on the shorter side (Yoda used one).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In both Canon and Legends, a pair of lightsabers functionally similar to Rey's potential new one were seen in the hands of the Besalisk Jedi Master [Pong Krell](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Pong_Krell%27s_lightsabers) during the Clone Wars. This picture shows them in their folded and extended configurations:

[image]

The lightsabers used by the Jedi Temple Guards in both [Canon](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_Temple_Guard) and [Legends](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_Temple_Guard/Legends) were aesthetically and functionally similar to Rey's potential lightsaber, but were only shown to be folding lightsabers in *Star Wars Rebels*, part of Canon. However, it should be pointed out that in *Rebels* the folding hilt was seen only in the hands of *one* Temple Guard, and since lightsabers were personalized weapons, it is possible that not every Temple Guard weapon had that feature.

Lightsabers in the hands of the Temple Guard during the Clone Wars:
[image: Old Republic Temple Guard]

*Clone Wars* Concept Art (note slanted emitter shrouds and lack of hinged section, unlike Pong Krell's lightsaber):
[image]

And while another answer already uses this video, I will include it for the sake of completeness and to point out the lightsaber at [1:32](https://youtu.be/hrHN6_X6iQ4?t=92) that appears to be the same as the Clone Wars Temple Guard weapon:

Answer (score 22):

In Disney canon, Star Wars Rebels, season 2 episode 18, "Shroud of Darkness", Kanan fights Jedi temple guards who have similar double-bladed folding lightsabers (the unfolding activation can be seen at 00:41s in the below video).